# Dynamically change content of tab2 using content selected in tab1 in extJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using extJs framework. I have created a window and my items json object has two tabs tab1 and tab2. Now tab1 has some images, If i select some image in tab1, content in tab2 should change automatically.

For example:-
Tab has image1 and image2
If I click on image1 in tab1, then tab2 should show you have selected image no 1
If I click on image2 in tab1, then tab2 should show you have selected image no 2

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/view/chooser/chooser.html
May be this could help you with something you want to do

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link but i am not sure whether it can fulfill my purpose or not.Still thanks a lot